# How to get different buttons to submit different mySQL queries

Tags: php, html, mysql, button, input

I'm trying to create a button in a HTML form that adds a number to the corresponding mySQL location. Basically, a voting option for a post. Right now, the buttons all do the same thing: they submit the original post query from the bottom. How do I make them act individually?

PHP:

```
                    if (!$thepipeline) {
                        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
                        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
                        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
                        exit;
                    }
                    if (!empty ($_POST)) { 
                        $squery = "INSERT INTO votes (votes) VALUE (1)";
                        print $squery;                                                      
                        $votes_result = mysqli_query ($thepipeline, $squery);
                    }
                    $query = "SELECT p.post_id, p.member_id, p.content, p.date_created, 
                    SUM(v.votes) AS votes_total
                    FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
                    votes v
                    ON p.post_id = v.post_id
                    GROUP BY post_id
                    ORDER BY votes_total;";
                    echo "<table>\n";
                    echo '<tr>
                    <td> USER ID</td>
                    <td> PROPOSAL</td> 
                    <td> DATE POSTED</td>
                    <td> SCORE</td>
                    </tr>';
                    if ($amorphous_cloud = mysqli_query ($thepipeline,$query)) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($amorphous_cloud)){
                            echo '<tr>
                            <td> ' . $row['member_id'].'</td>
                            <td> ' . $row['content'].'</td> 
                            <td> ' . $row['date_created'].'</td>
                            <td> ' . $row['votes_total'].'
                            <br><form method="POST"><input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" /></form></td>
                            </tr>';
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        print ":(";
                    }
                    echo "</table>\n";

                    ?>

                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="addpost">
                    <h3>Enter Proposal</h3>
                    <p>Off-topic posts will be deleted without warning.</p>
                    <?php

                    $member_id = $_GET['member_id'];
                    $content = $_GET['content'];

                    $link = mysqli_connect ('localhost', '******', '************,', '*************');

                    if (!$link) {
                        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
                        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
                        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
                        exit;
                    }
                    if (!empty ($_GET)) { 
                        $query = "INSERT INTO posts (member_id, content) VALUES ('".$member_id."', '".$content."')";
                        print $query;                                                       
                        $member_result = mysqli_query ($link, $query);
                    }

                    $user_query = "SELECT member_id, member_name FROM members"; 
                    $user_result = mysqli_query ($link, $user_query);
                    $user_html = "";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($user_result)) {
                        $user_html = $user_html . "<option value='".$row['member_id']."'>".$row['member_name']."</option>\n";

                    }

                    ?>

                    <form method="GET">

                    <!-- member -->
                    <p>Member</br>
                    <select name="member_id" >
                    <?php echo $user_html; ?>
                    </select>

                    </p>

                    <!-- date -->
                    <p>Content
                    </p>
                    <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </br>
                    <input type="submit" />
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `if ($amorphous_cloud = mysqli_query ($thepipeline,$query))` you need two equal sign here, with one you assign not compare, and second what you are trying to do here, i dont understand the logic

Comment: what your are trying to do here as well ?? `<br><form method="POST"><input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" /></form></td>` this line not making any sense and above one too, in short with this form you will not be able to send any value, as there are not value in this form, only thing you have is one submit button.

Comment: I see. I've changed the input to a button, like so: `<button type="submit" value="$b">Vote</button>`. This references `if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
      $a="UPDATE votes SET votes=votes+1 WHERE post_id=post_id";
      $b=mysqli_query($a);
     }`

Does that make more sense?

Comment: `<br><form method="POST"><input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" /></form></td>` The reason i said this line is making any sense, is this that, when ever you click on the submit button, it takes what ever input field you got in between the form tag, in here you have no input feild, means you will not grab any value after clicking on the submit, and for second problem read the second comment,

Comment: first read the comment above `if ($amorphous_cloud = mysqli_query ($thepipeline,$query))`  this line is not making sense for two reason, first you are using equal sign, which simply means, for example $x=4 means x is equal to 4 and $x==4, check weather x is equal to 4 or not, two completly different thing, second reason is this `$amorphous_cloud = mysqli_query ($thepipeline,$query)` i am guessing you are trying to compare weather two values are equal or not, but this portion is only going to return object, so how you are going to compare them, you will be better off if  ...............

Comment: if you check weather your query is returning any row or not, and one more point adding button instead of submit will not help, and if you can edit your code, it will be better, and comment what you are trying to do before every form, this form supposed to get value from here or this form supposed to run this query, hope i am clear now

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, the if statement works fine, I'm certain it's not the problem. What you're saying about the form makes a lot of sense though, so I'll try to find a way to make sure the button gets a value to draw from.

Comment: D.C you are missing the point, your if statement always going to work, and that's the big problem, the reason you used if statement, that check weather condition is matching or not, and if condition is matching run the code otherwise dont run the code, but if you use single equal, your if statement always going to run regardless, i am giving you some hint in the next comment so you can fix your code by your self, as it time to go, if you cant let me know i will post the solution

Comment: read the above comment first, if you want all the value to be used in the query, put your opening and closing form tag out of loop, and if you want use them as indivitual value, like as  i understood by your question, before using the value start the opening form tag, in this case your closing form tag is at the right place so dont change it, and instead of using like this `$row['member_id']` add the input tag around it, than you will be done, wish you luck